# how to download multiple images onload using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, download

I am trying to make changes to multiple images, I'm drawing images on separate canvases, and modifying the pixels and then I want to download them after the modification. 
I have a function that converts canvases to images, and I save all my new canvases in an array. 
when I try to iterate over the array and download each canvas, only the last image is actually downloaded, not all of them, even though all of them actually exist in my array, I've checked that in Chrome console after loading the web page.
this is my code for downloading the images :

```
for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
    Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(canvases[i], canvases[i].width, canvases[i].height);
  }
```

and I also get the following error in console:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/octet-stream:

I can't change the MIME type, but I don't think that's the problem since teh code successfully downloads the last image with the right format.

I also tried calling the function that saves the images with:
1. window.onload
2. when DOMcontentLoaded
3. in the body of my html page
4. document.onload

None of the above downloaded more than the last image. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Canvas2Image source code you can see the saveAsJPEG works by changing url href, see https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image/blob/master/canvas2image.js#L47

I'm guessing the browser delays the actual location href update until the javascript executing completes.

Try executing the file save in a timeout so each save will run on its own, like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
   (function(c,w,h) {   // wrapping in a function to avoid timeout using the same final value of `i`
      setTimeout(function() {
         Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(c,w,h);
      }, i*2000);
    })(canvases[i], canvases[i].width, canvases[i].height);
  }
```

Comment: can you can try with a longer timeout?   I edited the answer to increase the timeout

Comment: In this code the timeout wasn't the problem, apparently the library Canvas2Image changes (and not delays) the actual location href.
I used another library for that, BUT the timeout is important indeed, anything less than roughly i * 100 wont work. 
problem solved! thanks @iftah

Comment: To be honest I don't know exactly the root cause of the problem, it may be a browser bug. Since there is no difference between the single saveAsJPEG and the many in a loop I figured a timeout delay will work around the bug.